# Security Exception unhandled

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception

I am using the following method to get a response stream from a website -

```
HttpWebRequest request;
WebResponse response;

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string url = textBox1.Text;
        request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.BeginGetResponse(AfterRequest, null);

    }

    public void AfterRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {

            response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            using (StreamReader sd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string resultString = sd.ReadToEnd();
            }
            response.Close();

    }
```

However the code breaks when it reaches -

```
response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
```

With the error message -

```
SecurityException was unhandled by user code
```

What is causing this issue?

Hear is the full exception -

```
System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult     asyncResult)
at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.    <EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object     state)
at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

Comment: Where does your "request" object come from in the _AfterRequest_ method?  I would usually pass this object as the state of the IAsyncResult and cast it back inside the callback (AfterRequest)

Comment: Apologies I forgot those credentials now added, are you familiar with this error?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you are causing a cross-domain violation? (i.e. are you requesting content from a different website/domain?)  If that's not the case, can you catch the exception and paste all of the details into your question please?

Comment: I am trying to access a website outwith my silverlight front end yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by creating a web method that did exactly what the front end code did in the back end web service and then invoked it in the front end, I had already implemented the cross-domain access policy by adding those file previously.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make content available from a different website/domain in Silverlight, take a look at the following guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have both files in my web service directory. I am pretty sure it is something to do with this however Silverlight errors are horrendously unhelpful at times. I really am stuck on this one.